# Configuring KPI in dashboard designer

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, performancepoint, kpi

I'm configuring a KPI for my SharePoint 2010 site. Take this example of a "projects" list and a "project progress" field in this list which is shown in percentage. I want to configure a KPI for this field to show the average project progress.

now my problem is in the data mappings window. After I click change source and select my created data source, in the "dimensional data source mapping" window I select the appropriate field (namely, "project progress"). The problem is that I can not change "Aggregate members by" to Average, which is by default set to "Default". The reason is that it is disabled (grayed out).

I've searched everywhere without luck. Every blog and tutorial assume that this part of the window is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If the data type is not compatible with taking an average, the "average" aggregation type will be disabled. Also, please be sure that the data source is ADOMD and the "Use MDX tuple formula" is NOT checked.